# Error in ArcPy script building network

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, python-script-tool, error-999999

I am trying to use the network analysis toolset to build a route. I made the the tool in model builder initially and have tried to edit it to make it a script.

When I try to build the network I get the following error:[image]

The following is the current script:

```py
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
import os

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Network")
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#getting geodatabase
geoBase = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
arcpy.env.workspace = geoBase
arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace = geoBase
path = geoBase


#getting network database
network = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
#getting stops
Stops = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

Route = "Route"
Route__2_ = Route
Route__3_ = Route__2_
Routes = "Route\\Routes"
Current_Best_Route = geoBase + "\\current_bestRoute"

# Process: Build Network
arcpy.na.BuildNetwork(network)

# Process: Make Route Layer
arcpy.na.MakeRouteLayer(network, "Route", "Length", "USE_INPUT_ORDER",
                        "PRESERVE_BOTH", "NO_TIMEWINDOWS", "", "NO_UTURNS",
                        "", "NO_HIERARCHY", "", "TRUE_LINES_WITH_MEASURES", "")

# Process: Add Locations
arcpy.na.AddLocations(Route, "Stops", Stops, "Name Name #", "5000 Meters", "",
                      "Export_Output SHAPE;Trial_ND_Junctions NONE",
                      "MATCH_TO_CLOSEST", "APPEND", "NO_SNAP", "5 Meters",
                      "INCLUDE", "Export_Output #;Trial_ND_Junctions #")

# Process: Solve
arcpy.na.Solve(Route__2_, "SKIP", "TERMINATE", "", "")

# Process: Copy Features
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(Routes, Current_Best_Route, "", "0", "0", "0")

arcpy.CheckInExtension("network")
```

I am not sure how to fix the error. When I run the tool without the arcpy.na.BuildNetwork I get the error saying:

> ERROR 030024: Solve returned a failure. The network dataset has no
>   edge elements. It may be unbuilt. Failed to execute (Solve).

So it seems I must build it, but that won't work for some reason.

Comment: You should only need to build the network once, which make me wonder if you're providing the network in your 2nd parameter or your line feature class that participates in a network or that your network is dirty.

Comment: Please always provide error messages as formatted text rather than as a picture so that it is available to future searches.

Comment: I have the network dataset, but I didn't build it. It is just sitting in the Feature Dataset

Comment: Please place error messages as text in the body of the question. Images are not legible on all devices, and are not text searchable by others who encounter the same issue.